# Magento 2 | manipulate minicart product name

Tags: magento2, product, mini-cart

I want to manipulate the product name within the `minicart`.
Check the picture below:

I can't find out which template is generating this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the below code to your module **di.xml**:

**di.xml** path will be like below:

> app/code/[Vendor]/[Moduel]/etc/di.xml

Code for **di.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem" type="Vendor\Module\CustomerData\DefaultItem" />
</config>
```

Create one class **DefaultItem** under

> app/code/Vendor/Module/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php

add the below code to your **DefaultItem.php**:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\CustomerData;

class DefaultItem extends \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper,
        \Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data $msrpHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ConfigurationPool $configurationPool,
        \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data $checkoutHelper
    ){
        parent::__construct($imageHelper, $msrpHelper, $urlBuilder, $configurationPool, $checkoutHelper);
    }
    protected function doGetItemData()
    {
        $imageHelper = $this->imageHelper->init($this->getProductForThumbnail(), 'mini_cart_product_thumbnail');
        return [
            'options' => $this->getOptionList(),
            'qty' => $this->item->getQty() * 1,
            'item_id' => $this->item->getId(),
            'configure_url' => $this->getConfigureUrl(),
            'is_visible_in_site_visibility' => $this->item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility(),
            'product_id' => $this->item->getProduct()->getId(),
            'product_name' => $this->item->getProduct()->getName().'test', //Add you logic here for product name
            'product_sku' => $this->item->getProduct()->getSku(),
            'product_url' => $this->getProductUrl(),
            'product_has_url' => $this->hasProductUrl(),
            'product_price' => $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($this->item->getCalculationPrice()),
            'product_price_value' => $this->item->getCalculationPrice(),
            'product_image' => [
                'src' => $imageHelper->getUrl(),
                'alt' => $imageHelper->getLabel(),
                'width' => $imageHelper->getWidth(),
                'height' => $imageHelper->getHeight(),
            ],
            'canApplyMsrp' => $this->msrpHelper->isShowBeforeOrderConfirm($this->item->getProduct())
                && $this->msrpHelper->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($this->item->getProduct()),
        ];
    }
}
```

Run **setup:upgrade** if module is newly created then run **setup:di:compile**.
Hope this helps!

Comment: do you know how to override this file?

Comment: @L.Klmn Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Welcome. Happy to help!

Comment: I am facing override issue... same code apply.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by creating a copy of `app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html`

in my theme at app/design/frontend/Holy/mytheme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html

and updating the code to include:

```
<strong class="product-item-name">
    <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
    <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_sku}, text: product_sku"></a>
    <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, text: product_name"></a>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
    <!-- ko text: product_name --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</strong>
```

Comment: @L.Klmn welcome

Answer (score 2):

In the file, `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js`
if you check the function `getCartItems`, it does contains the data for the items in the cart.
My suggestion is to write a mixin that would extends this function

the template that renders the product name is `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html`.

you will see in this template the product_name is binded with knockout and therefore, once your mixin will have update the product name, your template should render the change without modifying this template